# bing spell check saves user's data?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

I use the Bing Spell Check in my app and I can't find information regarding non-persistent mode.
I want to make sure that this service configured to no-storage. (I know in LUIS there is some flag I need to enable so I assume this is also the case but I can't find the flag)

How to make sure no data regarding the text I send is being saved?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear there is a difference in non-persistent and non-logging data modes (the first term is **not** in context of the http mode). The first one is for non-personalized responses - logging may/may not happen - and the second one is no logging altogether.

LUIS supports no-logging (with log=off) mode. Bing spell check, for now, seems to support non-persistent mode only, which is also the default mode. If query doesn't contain ClientID, User-agent, ClientIP, or SessionID (all optional parameters), there is no way to trace back to particular user/browser/IP/session.